# Grab elements which custom attribute value contains string - xpath selenium

Tags: javascript, selenium, xpath

In some application there are div's with custom tip attribute:

```
<div tip="<b>Kobold łucznik</b>" style="left: 450px; top: 220px;">...</div>
<div tip="<b>Kobold łucznik</b>" style="left: 320px; top: 320px;">...</div>
```

I'm using nodeJs selenium webdriver to pull some data from this application. I found info that I can use xpath to grab elements which attribute is equal to something.

What I want to achieve is find all elements which value of custom attribute tip contain string: `'Kobold łucznik'`. I want to do that to be able to collect x and y from `left: x px` and `top: y px` and push it to some array of objects later on.

But the first step is to find all this elements.

I tried like this:

```
driver.findElements(webdriver.By.xpath('//@*[contains('Kobold łucznik','tip')]/..'))
```

But with no luck.

---

As @zx485 said in comment section the issue here is that `tip` attribute value has `<` in it. Unfortunately I can not change the `tip` value. The key for my app to work correctly is to grab those elements and I can not get the job done without doing it.

Comment: I can not change it now

Comment: Is there some work around so I can get this elements? It's necessary

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this should work

```
driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[contains(@tip,'Kobold łucznik')]")
```

or use css selector which fast and compatible with more browser

```
driver.findElements(By.css("div[tip*='Kobold łucznik']"))
```

Comment: Joe's given code has small issue, I corrected it. Please try again.  I verified the xpath `//div[contains(@tip,'Kobold łucznik')]` worked fine on my local

Comment: Actually now it worked. I wonder why @zx485 in comment section below question said that it's not gonna work and I can't use xpath to achieve my goal.

Comment: But for some reason now I can not convert first from webElements to string with this: `webElements[0].getAttribute('innerHTML')`. I mean I can but string is empty.

Comment: Is there any html inside those div tags you retrieved? or are you trying to retrieve the value inside tip attribute?

Comment: Sorry I was trying to get outerHTML, my bad.